# Getting Function for a DLL Address Following a Crash

Tags: windows, debugging, dll

I know that when an application crashes, the system reports that it crashed at location 0x00004b79 in mydll.dll.  I have the source code, and I have the binary, but I don't have a PDB or any listing files from the build of that DLL.

The crash is repeatable, but I can't install a debugger on the production machine, and the crash does not occur in development or debugging environments.  I have set up Dr. Watson, and I have a crash dump and Dr. Watson log file.

The Dr. Watson log file contains this disassembly for the function that was being executed:

```
        10604b70 8b442408         mov     eax,[esp+0x8]
        10604b74 8b542404         mov     edx,[esp+0x4]
        10604b78 50               push    eax
FAULT ->10604b79 8b4120           mov     eax,[ecx+0x20]    ds:0023:00000020=????????
        10604b7c 52               push    edx
        10604b7d 6801800000       push    0x8001
        10604b82 50               push    eax
        10604b83 ff156c946210 call dword ptr [mydll!DllUnregisterServer+0x1720c (1062946c)]
        10604b89 c20800           ret     0x8
```

(INT 3 instructions precede and succeed the assembly snippet above.)

The stack trace only includes the address mydll+0x4b79.  It doesn't give any caller information.

Loading up the crash dump in windbg didn't provide any additional information.

How can I determine in what function (or even better, which line of code) the crash occurred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a crash dump of your application and exmaine it using a debugger, WinDbg is the obvious choice here. A crash dump will give you a stack trace and detailed error information.

Edit: As for not being able to install a debugger, DrWatson is preinstalled and able to generate crash dumps which can then be examined on a different machine.

Comment: I've got a crash dump in WinDbg. However, still clueless as to which function I'm looking at.  Stack trace just has mydll.dll+0x4b79.  Disassembly is just a bunch of calls to other places in the DLL, mixed with lots of MOV, PUSH, and JZ instructions.

Comment: Easiest way? Rebuild the DLL with debug information, reproduce the crash. Harder, manual work: Trace the crash up to a known/exported function and work from there.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a rebuild and reinstall, but that's what I had to do. Thanks.